# Performance analysis Groovy vs Java

Tags: java, performance, groovy, performance-testing

I had some performance issues and was curious if Groovy may be the reason. I did a very simple test.

Both files I simply added into my src/main/groovy or repsectivly src/main/java folder.

Because jdk8 doesn't support executing .java files directly I used adopt open jdk 11 for the Java file and JDK8 for groovy files.

With my Java file I have an execution time from about 1 ms (I tried with JDK 8 and got around 2ms). With Groovy I have an execution time from 5-7 milli seconds.

I am using a PC (windows 10) with a i7-7700 and have 32 GB RAM. For the groovy file I am using groovy 2.5.15.

Are my measurements wrong or is this amount of slowness "normal"?

EDIT: Measured with 1 Millionen repetition:
jdk 11: 5ms
groovy: 17-72ms

I created these files:

Copytest.groovy

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Copytest {

    static class MyObject {
        private String field1
        private String field2
        private String field3
        private String field4
        private String field5

        String getField1() {

            return field1
        }

        void setField1(final String field1) {

            this.field1 = field1
        }

        String getField2() {

            return field2
        }

        void setField2(final String field2) {

            this.field2 = field2
        }

        String getField3() {

            return field3
        }

        void setField3(final String field3) {

            this.field3 = field3
        }

        String getField4() {

            return field4
        }

        void setField4(final String field4) {

            this.field4 = field4
        }

        String getField5() {

            return field5
        }

        void setField5(final String field5) {

            this.field5 = field5
        }

        MyObject copy() {
            final MyObject copy = new MyObject()
            copy.setField1(getField1())
            copy.setField2(getField2())
            copy.setField3(getField3())
            copy.setField4(getField4())
            copy.setField5(getField5())
            return copy
        }
    }


    static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final long currentTime = System.nanoTime()
        final MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
        myObject.setField1("1")
        myObject.setField2(null)
        myObject.setField3("3")
        myObject.setField4("4")
        myObject.setField5("5")
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            myObject.copy();
        }
        System.out.println("Took " + (((System.nanoTime() - currentTime) / 1000000) as Integer) + " milli seconds to copy")
    }
}
```

CopytestJ.java

```
class CopytestJ {

    public static class MyObject {
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
        private String field3;
        private String field4;
        private String field5;

        public String getField1() {

            return field1;
        }

        public void setField1(final String field1) {

            this.field1 = field1;
        }

        public String getField2() {

            return field2;
        }

        public void setField2(final String field2) {

            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        public String getField3() {

            return field3;
        }

        public void setField3(final String field3) {

            this.field3 = field3;
        }

        public String getField4() {

            return field4;
        }

        public void setField4(final String field4) {

            this.field4 = field4;
        }

        public String getField5() {

            return field5;
        }

        public void setField5(final String field5) {

            this.field5 = field5;
        }

        public MyObject copy() {
            final MyObject copy = new MyObject();
            copy.setField1(getField1());
            copy.setField2(getField2());
            copy.setField3(getField3());
            copy.setField4(getField4());
            copy.setField5(getField5());
            return copy;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        final MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.setField1("1");
        myObject.setField2(null);
        myObject.setField3("3");
        myObject.setField4("4");
        myObject.setField5("5");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            myObject.copy();
        }
        System.out.println("Took " + ((System.nanoTime() - currentTime) / 1000000) + " milli seconds to copy");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting 1 ms and 5 ms for Java and Groovy respectively in Eclispe on I9-8950

Comment: 1 and 4-5 ms here too.  `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.56.0.21-CA-linux64) (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)` and `Groovy Version: 3.0.9 JVM: 1.8.0_302 Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc. OS: Linux`

Comment: Thanks guys, that at least is much better

Comment: As a side note: you don't  need to write out those getters/setter with groovy, if you remove the `private` on the fields, groovy will generate those for you. If you want to have the final for the setter arguments, you can use `@AutoFinal`. But there is no difference in performance for me anyway...

Comment: Could you maybe start to rule more things out here? Granted that there
seems to be some discrepancy between Java and Groovy (and this is to be
expected), it should not be magnitudes.  Can you state the groovy
version?  Does it work fine outside of IntellJ?

Comment: Hello @cfrick I changed my original post to be more precise. Also thanks for your suggestions about private and so on. I did want to make files as similar as possible (I don't know how generation of getter/setter actually manipulates the performance. If you tell me, do this and that to boost groovy performance on Copytest.groovy I'm glad to try it out

Comment: It does neither hinder nor improve the performance (for me), but it reduces the written code by 50% or so and you end up with idiomatic groovy. And from your changes is it safe to assume, that the original 400-500 ms was a typo? Or has that vanished? It's very confusing. Another side node: you can mix java and groovy files/code - so if you are not willing to "pay" for groovy features by performance, just keep the faster java classes around where it matters.

Comment: As it doesnt affect performance it doesn't matter I didnt use the full feature set of groovy. As I said I wanted to make a most fair competition so I made the code as equal as possible. The 400-500ms was NOT a typo, that was my result when starting with IntelliJ instead of command line directly, that's why I REALLY was curious. And FYI: I took my groovy classes which were slowing my web site down and transformed them into plain java (letting the code as it is). The loading time went from 20 seconds to 0.5 seconds. I can't really explain, but keep this as reminder if you have performance issues